# No target="blank"?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

How do I make the code below not catch the elements `<a>` with the attribute `target="blank"`? Because `location.href = link.href;` opens in the same card (only links with `target="blank"` should open in a new card without animation).

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
if (event.target.tagName !== "A" || !event.target.href) return;
event.preventDefault();
var link = event.target;
document.body.style.opacity = 0;
document.body.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
location.href = link.href;
});
});
```

If more clarification is needed, please comment below!

Comment: Do you mean `target="_blank"`?

Comment: @Barmar i use `target="blank". And it works.

Comment: `target="anything"` will open a new window unless it's one of the special values `_self`, `_parent`, or `_top`.

Comment: I didn't even know that, thanks to me, I already know I have to improve it :) And on many pages I see somehow `target="blank"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `event.target.target`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName !== "A" || !event.target.href || event.target.target == "_blank") return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var link = event.target;
  document.body.style.opacity = 0;
  document.body.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    location.href = link.href;
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any idea that the request should be sent by the XHR and that the URL of the site should also change?

Comment: I think you can use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to change the URL.

Comment: I think to use just the XHR request to send it to the server and how will it return to display this return on the page then change the URL in the browser (I have something like this but the code obviously doesn't work...), I don't know how to make JS scripts work in the obtained code

Comment: That's difficult. jQuery does it by parsing the returned HTML, looking for `<script>` elements, and calling `eval()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I hate Jquery, maybe the code is easier to write but I don't prefer to use any libraries.

Comment: I wasn't saying you should use jQuery, just telling you how it gets around this problem.

Comment: You know how to write a code this way? I don't think it's that long, the one I have for this moment has about 10 lines (it doesn't interpret JS and doesn't change the URL.

Comment: Read the question I linked to, it has some code examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16278226/11860129 but this is interesing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below if condition:

`event.target.getAttribute('target') !== blank);`

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)